# Energy conservation in a balloon

Tags: energy-conservation, work

If a helium balloon moves up with a net acceleration a then does its potential and kinetic energies increase simultaneously?

Answer (score 3):

The balloon alone is what we call an *open system*, in which forces from outside the system can change the dynamics inside of it. This is because the balloon interacts with the atmosphere, and the result of this interaction is the buoyant force. The buoyant force on the balloon is what causes it to accelerate upward (specifically, it's due to the fact that the buoyant force is stronger than gravity for the balloon). This buoyant force transfers energy from the atmosphere to the balloon; as such, the balloon's potential and kinetic energy both increase, because energy is flowing into the balloon from the atmosphere. If you were to consider the balloon and atmosphere together, energy would be conserved in that system, as it is a *closed system**.

*This assumes that the atmosphere does not transfer energy to the Earth.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have a massless spherical balloon of radius $r$ filled with a gas of density $\rho$ immersed in a fluid of density $\sigma$ with $\sigma > \rho$.

The weight of the gas is $W_{\rm balloon} =\frac 43 \pi r^3 \rho g$ and the weight of the displaced fluid is $W_{\rm fluid} =\frac 43 \pi r^3 \rho g$ which is the magnitude of the upthrust on the balloon.

As $\sigma > \rho$ then $W_{\rm fluid} > W_{\rm balloon}$ so there is a net upward force on the gas of $W_{\rm fluid} - W_{\rm balloon}$ and that is why, if released, the balloon accelerates upwards.

Consider the balloon alone as the system.
There are two forces on the balloon $W_{\rm fluid}$ upwards (the upthrust, force on balloon due to the fluid surrounding it) and  $W_{\rm balloon}$ downwards (the weight of the balloon, the gravitational attraction due to the Earth on the balloon).
The net work done by these two forces on the balloon when it rises a distance $h$ is $W_{\rm net}  = (W_{\rm fluid} - W_{\rm balloon}) h$ and this is equal to the increase in kinetic energy of the balloon $\Delta U_{\rm kinetic}$.

Now consider the balloon, the fluid and the Earth as the system with the balloon rising a distance $h$ and assume that the Earth and fluid have a much greater mass than the balloon.

The **gain** in gravitational potential energy of the balloon is $W_{\rm balloon}h$ and the **loss** in gravitational potential of the fluid is $W_{\rm fluid}h$ with a net **decrease** in the gravitation potential energy of the system of  $(W_{\rm fluid} - W_{\rm balloon}) h$.
The decrease in gravitational potential energy is equal to the increase in the kinetic energy of the system (the balloon) $\Delta U_{\rm kinetic}$, and gains kinetic energy the same as that found considering the balloon as the system.